# Where to Put DLLs to be Used by VS 2017 SSDT

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2017, ssdt-2017

I have an SSRS project that I created using VS 2015 SSDT. It has a reference to barcodelib.dll that's used to create a barcode on the report.

The problem is that I got a new PC, and it uses VS 2017 SSDT. Now every time I run it, I get the error:

```
Error while loading  code module: The system cannot find the file specified
```

I have tried adding the dll in every folder for VS on this computer, there's 10 - 14:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio (number from 10-14)\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio (number from 10-14)\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies

But it still cannot find the file.

How do I figure out where it's looking?

Comment: Try going to one of the reports that uses the 3rd party barcode and navigate from the tool bar "Report" | "Report Properties" and click on "References". Then once the reference has been updated, you can do a find and replace in the report solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location I needed to put the DLL file was:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\SQL\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\SSRS